# jQuery changing background for each li with css

Tags: jquery, css, background, html-lists, nav

I have a 1 page portfolio with a navigation div holding three "li" items with three different background images,
and there's a different background image for each "li" item when you hover.

```
#nav li.portfolio a:link, #nav li.portfolio a:visited {background:url(../img/icon_folio.png) no-repeat 10px 5px; display:block;}
#nav LI.portfolio a:hover, #nav LI.portfolio a:active, li.portfolio.active {background:url(../img/icon_folio.png) no-repeat 10px -100px;}

#nav li.about a:link, #nav li.about a:visited {background:url(../img/icon_me.png) no-repeat 10px 5px; display:block;}
#nav li.about a:hover, #nav li.about a:active {background:url(../img/icon_me.png) no-repeat 10px -105px;}
```

What I want is somehow to target each link when clicked to be a selected element,
something like `$('#nav li a').click(function(){
           $('#nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});`

the problem in this code is that it calls for the new background ***behind*** the current one!

is there a way to actually remove the current background when I click, and replace it with the one used in the hover ??

Thank you so much in advance, I have learned and fixed a lot of problems through this website!

Comment: Will you be disabling the link when clicked?  Like when displaying a menu? I can't think of why else you'd want a click effect for a link that goes to another page anyway. I don't mean to be snarky; just trying to understand your problem.

Comment: oh no no no, u're totally right! the links dont send u to other pages, its a **1 page portfolio**.. the page slides to different sections.. 
sorry that's my bad :)

Comment: Man, it's hard to understand your explanation. =/

Comment: @Jayme, Three links, u click on one the page slides to a specific section, u click on another, the page slides to a different section. what I want is, when u click on a link, to have a selected status, when u click on another link, the selected status goes to the other link and so on!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$('#nav li a').toggle(

        function() {

            $('#nav li').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

            },
        function() {

            $('#nav li').addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
        }

    );
```

With differnet backgrounds for each 'active' and 'inactive'

You can also look at `.toggleClass()` [Jquery toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: well, the trick is, for each clicked 'li' to remain with its 'active' background, and when you click on another 'li' link, the other will have its 'active' background and that last one will go back to its normal background!.. I hope I'm making sense..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @Alfie-101,
you solution inspired me, not sure if my approach is neat enough but it works like a charm

```
$('#nav li').addClass('inactive');

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    $('#nav li').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

    $(this).parent().removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

    });`
```